# Get rid of \ character on mysql_real_escape_string() parsed string

Tags: php, mysql, database

My problem seem's trivial but I havn't found any "good" solution to this.

First a question that I've heard many answers on, when to we need to parse a string with `mysql_real_escape_string()`? My thought is that it's only needed when to store user given data in a database, is that a good rule to follow?

My second question and that's the real problem. When I parse a string with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, it will put a special character `\` before any harmful character in the string, ex. if the function finds a `'` then it will be appended with a `\` so the result is `\'`.

Well ok, that's fine, the problem is when I read the same string from the database, then I also get the `\` character. Is there any good way to get rid of `\` character?
One thought I've had is to use the `str_replace("\\","",$string)`, but is this a good and safe way to do this?

Thank you all!

Comment: This isn't caused by that function, it's caused by the PHP settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, the use of mysql_real_escape_string is discouraged. Check if magic_quotes are on:

```
echo "Magic quotes is " . (get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? "ON" : "OFF");
```

Or you can use `stripslashes`

Comment: Thanks! I will check the magic qoutes. Ok so mysql_r_e_s is discouraged, is it because the use of a mysql_function or why is it discouraged??
Is it ok to use the mysqli_r_e_s, if not, how to clean strings from crap?

Comment: The best thing would be to use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php . For many reasons is better for you to use PDO. Also check out this link : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 2):

you you can use [stripslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

eg:

```
<?php
    $text = "Test\'ing my app";
    echo stripslashes($text);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) does not place permanent `\` in your strings. It only uses them up-until it finishes inserting.

The most-likely cause of the backslashes in your string is by the use of [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes), or if [`Magic Quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are on by default in your environment.

You can remove them using PHP's [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) in any case:

```
$string = stripslashes($string);
```

Another reference for `mysql_real_escape_string()` is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `\` characters added my [`m_r_e_s`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) don't actually get inserted into the DB.  If you are getting these on retrieval its because something like [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) is enabled and you are getting slashes added automatically.

### That said, you should really switch to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) since the `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

You are correct with your first question, any user input should be properly escaped before being inserted.  PDO and Mysqli allow you to use prepared statements, and also provide their own escaping functions.

In regards to your second question, try some code like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $value = stripslashes($_POST['value']);
}
```

This will remove any slashes added automatically by PHP.  More info on [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: Why is the mysql_functions deprecated? I've never heard about this so an explanation would be good..

Comment: See the table [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  Basically they lack support for a number of features (e.g. prepared statements and transactions). Also they are not object oriented.  Now that the deprecation process has begun, we can expect that these functions will no longer exist in some future version of PHP although there is nothing official at the moment.

Comment: All of the manual pages for the [mysql_](http://php.net/mysql_query) functions have the red box explaining the [deprecation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Comment: Hmm it seems like I have a bit of refactoring ahead;-) I agree by your explanation that it's wiser to use mysqli, so thanks for the information!

Comment: It's something to think about at least.  Mysqli is a good starting point if you are coming from mysql_ functions.  Very little difference to get used to.  Hopefully you don't have to change too much :)